# Extract substrings in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, regex, string

Suppose I have a string of random characters with quoted strings inside like this:

> a:15:i:0s:3:"FOO"i:1s:3:"BAR"i:2s:3:"BAZ"i:3s:3:"ALPHA100"i:4s:3:"ALPHA500"i:5s:3:"BRAVO250"i:6s:3

I'd like to match the quoted strings inside which always contain either three uppercase letters or five uppercase letters followed by three numbers. In JavaScript I can do this:

```
" the string ".match(/"([A-Z]{3}|[A-Z]{5}\d{3})"/g);
```

I've looked into the [`REGEXP`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/regexp.html) operator for MySQL but that seems to only be applicable for conditional clauses.

Ideally I'd like to select all the strings, trim off the quotation marks, and do a `GROUP_CONCAT` to get back a final result set of one row like this:

```
"FOO,BAR,BAZ,ALPHA100,ALPHA500,BRAVO250"
```

Ideally I'd like to do this at the database level to avoid downloading all the strings and running them through my one-line JavaScript program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll show a function that is based on string splitting as shown in [SQL split values to multiple rows](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17942508/3501730) to be used like

```
SELECT get_the_parts(theString) FROM example;
```

This function works as this:
- split the string into a table with parts using the double quote as delimiter
- select only those parts that match exactly 3 upper case letters or 5 upper case letters followed by three digits
- concatenates the selected parts with the comma as separator

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE FUNCTION get_the_parts(myString VARCHAR(2000)) RETURNS VARCHAR(2000)
BEGIN
  DECLARE result VARCHAR(2000);

  SELECT
    GROUP_CONCAT(t.value) INTO result
    FROM (
      SELECT
        SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(e.col, '"', n.n), '"', -1) value
      FROM ( SELECT myString AS col ) e
      CROSS JOIN (
        -- creates a numbers table with the values from 1 to 1,000 on the fly
        SELECT 
            1 + a.N + b.N * 10 + c.N * 100 AS n
        FROM
            (SELECT 0 AS N UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9) a
            ,(SELECT 0 AS N UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9) b
            ,(SELECT 0 AS N UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9) c
        ORDER BY n    
      ) n
      WHERE
        n.n <= 1 + LENGTH(myString) - LENGTH(REPLACE(myString, '"', '')) 
    ) t
    WHERE 
        t.value REGEXP '^([A-Z]{3}|[A-Z]{5}[0-9]{3})$';

    return result;
END //
DELIMITER ;
```

## Explanation

**Creating a numbers table**

The innermost subselect with the `UNION ALL` creates on the fly a numbers table with the numbers from 1 to 1000. This subselect could easily substituted by a numbers table in your database.

**Splitting the string**

With a nested call of [SUBSTRING_INDEX](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index) we cut the n-th substring between the separators. We use the double quote as separator:

```
SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(e.col, '"', n.n), '"', -1)
```

The expression

```
1 + LENGTH(myString) - LENGTH(REPLACE(myString, '"', ''))
```

gives us the count of parts, because it's one occurrence more than occurrences of the separator.

**Selecting the wanted parts**

We use the the regexp

```
'^([A-Z]{3}|[A-Z]{5}[0-9]{3})$'
```

because our parts have got to exactly match the known regexp from the beginning `^` until the end `$` without having more content.

**Concatenating**

Lastly we use GROUP_CONCATE with the default separator, the comma, to get the desired result.

## Remarks

I've built a <kbd>[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/631b3e/3)</kbd>.
You can easily modify this function to meet your needs.
Do you really prefer this? I would recommend to use your one-line javascript. Text processing of this form isn't really what relational databases are best.

Comment: This is certainly quite the function, but I think I'll stick to my line of JavaScript code :-P